# Where to put domain folders in IIS7? InetPUb / wwwroot?

Tags: iis, iis-7

Can anyone tell me what the standard is for creating new domain directories for inetpub in IIS

Is the standard to put in directly under inetpub on the same level as wwwroot or actually inside wwwroot??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a better question.

Why would you WANT a standard solution?  Most script kiddies and amateur hackers rely on the fact that people put things in the same places all the time and use the same ports.

A good example of this is the SSH port on port 22.  It gets POUNDED all the time but if you move it to something like 11022 you'll find the attacks all but stop.

Looking for the "cgi-bin" directory on a website is another common example.

Using that style of logic, I know many people who create their IIS web directories somewhere non-standard such as c:\websites\sitename1, c:\websites\sitename2, etc

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree, I never put any web data on the C drive, there are Data drives for that.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have said d:\websites\sitename1 but didn't want to lead to another (offtopic) discussion.  Was trying to keep it simple. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Inside WWWRoot

Answer (score 0):

Quite apart from not understanding what you mean by "domain folders", what difference does it make? Put them where you like but for what it's worth, I wouldn't put them on a system drive. If anyone later needs to know their physical location they can just consult your documentation.